# Understanding Random Experiment

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am self-learning probability and statistics and I am trying to understand probability at a deeper level. As part of my learning so far, I understand that

- An event is a set of outcomes of a random experiment.

Now, I am working through a problem which roughly states:

Let **A** be the event that a person has a disease and **B** be the event that a test for the disease is positive, indicating the person tested has the disease. Then there are bunch of conditional probabilities given involving A and B and I need to solve for something.

My Question is:

Since A and B are events, and there are some conditional probabilities involving for both of them, what is the **random experiment** for which **A** and **B** are the events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a random choice among the possible outcomes of the cartesian product of the domains of events $A,B$, which is ($D$: has disease, $T$: test positive):
$$\mathcal{S}=\{(D,T),(D,T'),(D',T),(D',T')\}$$
Here, event $A$ is the set $\{(D,T),(D,T')\}$ and event $B$ is the set $\{(D,T),(D',T)\}$.

Practically, you can think of an experiment where you first choose a random number, $u$, in $U[0,1]$ and let the person has the disease if $u<P(D)$ and not o/w. Following this, you'll take another sample from $U[0,1]$ and compare it with $P(T|D=d)$ similarly, where you have your sample from the set above, $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you! There were a few gaps in my understanding.

I was thinking of a RE as only containing a single step, like tossing a coin, but now i understand that it could by multi-step too. For example, drawing a card after throwing a dice.